# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission azureserver.database.windows.net:1433 connect,resolve)

Tags: security, azure

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /azure.jsp at line 18

    15:                 ;
    16:      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    17:                     
    18:         Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    19:             if(connect!=null)
    20:                 out.println("Connected");
    21:             else
------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission sahilpaudel.database.windows.net:1433 connect,resolve)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionSecurityManager.checkConnect(SQLServerConnection.java:3218)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerPortPlaceHolder.doSecurityCheck(FailOverInfo.java:144)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ServerPortPlaceHolder.<init>(FailOverInfo.java:135)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:984)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:816)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    org.apache.jsp.azure_jsp._jspService(azure_jsp.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Am trying to connect to azure database from jsp page but i am getting this error
I have added firewall settings but it is still coming. Azure,jsp is my jsp file name that is in the online server.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add that to the policy file and see if that helps? Actually, it is a very old issue type, and should have nothing with the cloud specifics.

```
grant
{
...
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1433","connect,resolve";
};
```

Comment: thanks u replied but where to locate this policy file?